# camera slider image getting cropped from sides

Tags: jquery, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pkdpap6/)

I am trying to use Camera Slider by pixedelic for slideshow. But all the images getting cropped in it from sides. So I edited the camera.js file at and removed the negative margins like below:

```
t.css({
                                'height' : h,
                                'margin-left' : 0,
                                'margin-right' : 0,
                                'margin-top' : 0,
                                'position' : 'absolute',
                                'visibility' : 'visible',
                                'width' : wT*r
                            });
```

After doing this image shows complete on left but getting cropped on right side now. I have tried many things at runtime but unable to get it working as expected.

See the current output:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what the variables h wT and r mean. But maybe use `'max-width': '100%'`?

Comment: check fidddle https://jsfiddle.net/9pkdpap6/

Comment: @RMo not working,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your height and width values are being set to whatever your jQuery carousel plugin determines is the appropriate size.  A way to force the issue with CSS is to set the following in your CSS file:

```
.cameraSlide img {
   max-width: 100% !important;
   width: auto !important;
   height: auto !important;
}
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pkdpap6/2/)

The `!important` modifier isn't best practice, and for good reason.  It kills all specificity rules in CSS.  However, if you're not planning on modifying anything else with this plugin, this solution will work.  This will override the inline styles applied by JavaScript and force the rules you define in CSS.  Being unfamiliar with the control nor wanting to go digging through its documentation, this is the quickest and easiest solution I have for you.

Comment: Actually I have spent alot of time on setting it. But in vain. So acc. to me its perfect solution as it works fine. But I used only max-width

Comment: Be aware if you only use `max-width` you're likely to see some distortions on the base image once the container shrinks below its natural width.